# Error while trying to create a password confirmation validator (Expected validator to return Promise or Observable)

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error. Each time I type in, the following error is shown:

> Error: Expected validator to return Promise or Observable.

Code I'm trying get working:

**Validator**:

```
export function passwordMatchValidator(passwordKey: string, passwordConfirmationKey: string, group: FormGroup): any {

    if (group) {
        if (group.get(passwordKey).value !== group.get(passwordConfirmationKey).value) {
            return { 'passwordMismatch': true };
        }
    }

    return null
}
```

**FormGroup** code:

```
this.formGroup.setValidators(passwordMatchValidator("password", "confirmPassword", this.formGroup));
this.formGroup.updateValueAndValidity();
```

**HTML**:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="formGroup.controls['confirmPassword'].errors?.passwordMismatch"></mat-error>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have created a simple [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8lsv9f?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) example.

**formGroup**

```
this.formGroup = new FormGroup(
  {
    password: new FormControl(),
    passwordConfirm: new FormControl()
  },
  { validators: passwordMatchValidator }
);
```

**Validator**

```
export function passwordMatchValidator(g: FormGroup) {
   return g.get("password").value === g.get("passwordConfirm").value
     ? null
     : { mismatch: true };
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  Password: <input formControlName="password"  placeholder="Password"><br>
  Confirm Password: <input formControlName="passwordConfirm" placeholder="Confirm Password"><br>
  <span *ngIf="formGroup.errors && formGroup.errors.mismatch" 
  [style.color]="'red'">Password Mismatch</span><br>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button> 
 </form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, but it's similar to my code. I've just fixed it by replacing the validation function

Comment: Cheers @prevox.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by importing **ValidationErrors** like this:

```
export function passwordMatchValidator(passwordKey: string, passwordConfirmationKey: string): ValidatorFn {

    return (group: FormGroup): ValidationErrors  => {
        const control = group.controls[passwordKey];
        const matchingControl = group.controls[passwordConfirmationKey];

        if (matchingControl.errors && !matchingControl.errors.passwordMismatch) {
            // return if another validator has already found an error on the matchingControl
            return;
        }

        // set error on matchingControl if validation fails
        if (control.value !== matchingControl.value) {
            matchingControl.setErrors({ 'passwordMismatch': true});
        } else {
            matchingControl.setErrors(null);
        }
        
        return;
    }
}
```